# Problems swapping an array element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I'm a TA and a student came in asking why the following code didn't swap the first 2 elements in an array and instead resulted as undefined. Here's the code the student showed me:

```
var swapFirstTwoElementsOf = function (a) {
    a = [a[1],a[0]].concat(a.slice(2, a.length));
}
```

Why does this return undefined?

Comment: 1.4 I believe. I'm using the shell here: http://www.squarefree.com/shell/shell.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the variable. The local reference is reassigned, but the original variable a is not. You need to do something like

```
var swapFirstTwoElementsOf = function (a) {
    return [a[1],a[0]].concat(a.slice(2, a.length));
}

var myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3];
myArray = swapFirstTwoELementsOf(myArray);
```

Previously, the function was evaluating to undefined because it wasn't returning anything.

Comment: No problem. I often spend ages on a problem ,finally ask SO, then find some silly solution. Cheers!

Comment: Note that `var tmp = a[0]; a[0] = a[1]; a[1] = tmp;` would swap the first two elements of the original array without the function needing to return anything - you can't reassign the original variable from inside the function, but you can modify the object it already references. (Though I realise the code was a question from a student so suggesting alternative methods may or may not be appropriate.)

Comment: If I noticed the student/TA part I would claim to be the student to mess around!